# Deleting records from a huge table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have table in my application which stores the data like pid (primary key) and (inst id) which stores keeps the history data and rows with latest inst id has the latest data.

sample data has below:

Ex: tablename is TESTTABLE ( pid number,instid number,datacol1 varchar2(100),datacol2 date);

```
pid     instid      datacol1    datacol2

---------------------------------------
1       18      sample1     2/05/2012

1       17      sample2     2/04/2013

1       16      sample2     2/04/2013

2       15      sample3     1/04/2012

2       14      sample3     2/04/2012
```

Above results , latest record for pid 1 id is instid 18 and for pid 2 is 15.
Now the table has grown billions of records and size is too huge (around 1 TB)
,planning to clear history data , keeping latest (pid,instid) combination and delete rest.

Can anyone suggest me what's the better approach to delete the rows considering the huge size of table.

Comment: Yes.  Store the data in partitions and drop partitions.  Hopefully that is how such a large table is organized.

Comment: Deleting records from table of billions of records will be always problem . You have to implement partition table , then drop old partition. delete by sql stm will have high cpu , & disk i/o ; Partition table will give good benefit for you application performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be a multi stage operation consisting of 1)  creating an extraction script/proc that builds a new table, holding just the needed rows.  This will raise the question of how many recent revisions are needed, which is a must-answer question.  Design it to place the output into a new table.  Once that is written and tested and approved by the users, then pick a time to suspends new activity, run the sql program to create the new table.  Archive the ENTIRE old table to a medium that allows you to restore selectively.  Truncate the original table, and reload it using the contents from the step 1 extract.  TEST, TEST, TEST and get user buyoff every step of the way.

Comment: Thanks for answering @jsbaltes . This approach has been tested in UAT and approved by users too. But since the volume of data is huge in Prod, not really sure this has to be done in batch or any other approach. So that deleting data from the table shouldn't take more than a day.

Comment: if you dont have an SQL for it yet...I think this will do it :
Select  t1.pid, t1.instid, t2.datacol1, T2.DATACOL2
From    (  
            Select  pid, 
            Max(Instid) instid
            From  TESTDATA
            Group By Pid
        ) T1
Inner
Join    TESTDATA T2
  On    T2.Pid = T1.pid
  and   t2.instid = t1.instid
Order
  by    t1.pid
    ,   t1.instid

Comment: If the amount of data that will be retained is relatively small ( 30 % or less ), then I recommend going to a new table with it, and then doing a double rename, so the old table takes on a name like TESTDATE_BKP and the new table becomes TESTDATA.  Then re-add indexes, constraints etc to the new table.  Your downtime will be shortened and your recover file will be right there, accessible as needed.   Then after a  safety period, backup and delete the orginal table.    Delete transactions will flood the Txn log...so I don't recommend that route.

Answer (score 1):

Since your taking about "billions of records " and "planning to clear history data"  i would suggest you should go for table partition may be partition by week or month, then you can easily drop the older partition.

yes ,  this need some design change but its worth doing give good for applications and give benefit for long run.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be useful if you want to just keep the most recent ones.

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY pid DESC) AS Rn
            ,pid
            ,instid
            ,datacol1
            ,datacol2
    FROM TESTTABLE
)
DELETE FROM C
WHERE Rn != 1

SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE
```